# AngularJS - SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' error in Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari

I don't get any errors on Chrome and website is working. But, in safari most of the pages doesn't load at all. This is the error i get:

```
[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' (angular.min.js.map, line 2)
```

I use the angular.min.js file I've downloaded from here: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.12/

Any ideas?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an end quote after "A;;;;;aAKC,SAAQ,CAACA,CAAD,

Comment: I just use the file I've downloaded from angular web site. It can't be wrong. https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.12/

Answer (score 0):

If you do not plan to debug using the developer console in Chrome, you can remove this JavaScript source map file 'angular.min.js.map' from your site's markup.  It will save you the "unnecessary" 404, however it shouldn't hurt by being there either.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting same error in chrome also, as a **temporary** solution to remove this error is to include angular.js instead of angular.min.js to html page and remove angular.min.js.map from our html page.

Answer (score 0):

Put whole angular.map.js to parenthesis (). The quoted "" starts an expression statement inside the block, but then the next token after the string is a colon, and there's no expression form that looks like an expression followed by a colon.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the following steps I took to resolve this issue, 
1. Order of js file reference changed,
2. A variable is set to null value, I changed that to make it work.